# sox (SOund eXchange): How to detect audio devices that can use to recording/playing?

Tags: xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, audio-recording

I'm using `sox` that installed with homebrew.

Although I can play audio stream/audio file with "play" command, but when I using `rec -d sample.wav`, I got nothing, just a file with blank sound.

I tried to use the same device id that worked with arecord as "arecord -D hw:0,0 -c 2"... but stills a blank sound.

So my quesion: how to know and to specify input devices (or output, for `play` version) for `sow` version installed by homebrew?

Many thanks in advance.
I searched Google but couldn't find any relevant answers.

Btw, I use PulseAudio as the default audio server on my Xubuntu 20.04.

edit:
`sox` install with apt also have same problem.